# Android : SharedPreferences data lifetime

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

For example if I do it once in my application :

```
sharedPref.edit().putString("com.blablabla.name_user","COCORICO").apply();
```

Can I find the data as long as the application is installed ?

```
String name_user = sharedPref.getString("com.blablabla.name_user", "");
```

Except if I reinstall the application or if I overwrite the data,

the data will never be lost, even several months later ?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be deleted. It will be deleted only if:

- user clears application data
- user reinstalls the application
- user manually deletes SP data

  SharedPreferences is made to save **key values**, such as settings, etc.
  You can find your SP file in /data/data/you.apk.package.name/shared_prefs/

Answer (score 0):

Why you think data should lost, unless you modified/deleted it?

You can read more about shared perferences here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

If you will uninstall application all shared perferences will be deleted. If it will be updated in correct way (signed with same keys) - not.

Comment: OK so it will not be deleted when we update the application ! cool ! thanks

Comment: Yes but you will need to use same keystore for all updates.